# Find the column space of the matrix $ \left(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 1 & -1 & 2 &0\\ \end{smallmatrix}\right) $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I have the following matrix

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 1\\
    0 & 1 & -1 & 2 &0\\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

And I am unsure as to how to write the column space/image for the transformation it represents.

I know that, for a Mapping $M:S\to R$, $\operatorname{Im}(M)$ is the subspace of elements $x$ of $R$ for which there is some element $y$ of $S$ such that $M(y)=x$.

Should I write the Image as $$\operatorname{Im}(M)=
    \left(\begin{matrix}
    x_{1}-x_3+x_5\\
    x_{2}-x_3+2x_4\\
    \end{matrix}\right)
$$

for $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5 \in\mathbb R$?????

Comment: If you find the reduced row echelon form, you can write everything in terms of the free variables then write it in terms of two vectors that span a plane.

Comment: To put @Omega's answer another way: notice that the first two columns generate $\Bbb R^2$. With only two rows, you can't get any bigger than this, so the other columns are redundant. Therefore the column space is $\Bbb R^2$. (You could make exactly the same argument using, say, columns $3$ and $5$; it's just columns $1$ and $2$ are the obvious choice.)

Answer (score 1):

That is not the image space, that is just another way to write the transformation. The image space is the entire $R^2$, since for any vector $(x,y)$, at least the vector $(x,y,0,0,0)$ is mapped onto it.

Answer (score 0):

The image space is generated by the images of the vectors  in the basis of $\mathbf R^5$ chosen to represent the transformation. Now, these images are precisely the $5$ column vectors. As they contain the vectors $\;\begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ and $\;\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}$ , which are a basis of $\mathbf R^2$, this means the image space is  equal to $\mathbf R^2$.

Comment: So is the image space generated by all the linearly independent columns of the matrix representing the transformation?

Comment: The vector columns, independent or not, are a set of generators of the image space.

Comment: "As they contain the vectors (1,0) and (0,1) , which are a basis of R2, this means the image space is equal to R2." Why does it mean that?

Comment: If you have a basis, you have the whole space.

Comment: So is the Image space is the space spanned by the 5 column vectors. But in this case since the other three are just a combination of the first two, and the first two span the entire R2 set, the image space is R2?

Comment: It's exactly that.

Comment: So when we reduce to row echelon form first, is that just to make sure the system is consistent?